# GIS projects with a raspberry pi

Tags: research

Does anyone know of a project using a raspberry pi and gis that would work for a research project for a computer science major? I am looking to do a research project involving a raspberry pi and incorporating gis into it. I am also looking to use python but all ideas are welcome. Very broad but looking for any ideas. Possibly a mapping application.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! R-pi and GIS are both really expansive fields/topics. It sounds like an awesome idea, but I think your question is a bit too broad currently.

Comment: Note the R-pi runs on an ARM processor (think the same technology that your mobile phone uses). This may limit what "GIS" type of applications you could run on it (if thats what you want to do). I used a Rpi + GPS + 3G phone to act as a sort of tracker. I captured points and pushed them back to ArcGIS Online. So in terms of the Pi being a sensor, theres lots of potential. But like Paul said, very broad question. If you could give some focus or possible direction to your question maybe it will spurn ideas.

Comment: Artem Pavlenko, creator of Mapnik and now with Mapbox, demonstrated running Tilemill 2 on a Raspberry Pi at State of the Map 2013: http://vimeopro.com/openstreetmapus/state-of-the-map-us-2013/video/68087551

Comment: another project is geopoppy by Julien Ancelin using Docker for runing QGiserver + Postgis + Lizmap webapp. check this on github